# Reuse only some parameters on Crystal Reports refresh?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Reports which takes 2 parameters.  One of these is set automatically by the C# app that runs the report, but the other is set by the user.  I would like to make it so that when the user refreshes the report, only the parameter that was entered by the user is prompted for.

I'm aware of the ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh property, but this make it so that ALL parameters are reused.  I have also tried appending the refreshreports method, but this doesn't seem to work.  When I look at the viewer's Refresh() method's definition, all I get is an abstract class with undefined methods, so I'm not sure where to look.

Has anyone dealt with this sort of issue before?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a partial refresh via Crystal. You'll need to build your own parameter window and set them yourself, and display your prompt on the refresh.

One simple work-around that you may have not thought of is to remove the parameter that you set and either

a) hardcode your own record selection criteria in the report 
b) pass your own record selection criteria when the report runs

The whole reason you're setting the parameter is so you can help select the records. You can do that via setting your own record selection, too.