# Crystal report viewer losing parameter on refresh

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

I have set some report parameters programatically and it workds fine but when user hits refresh , crystal report prompts for those parameter values too. I am trying to reset those parameters by handling crystal viewer refresh but unable to do so. any ideas?

Comment: Check this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/48821144/1225070

Comment: I should have mentioned i am working on windows app. the above link pertains to web app

Comment: my question seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171625/reuse-only-some-parameters-on-crystal-reports-refresh

Answer (score 0):

I was able to suppress the parameter prompt completely by disabling the crystal report refresh button and replacing it with my own button and methods , help taken from here
http://www.it-sideways.com/2011/10/how-to-disable-parameter-prompt-for.html